# vb 6.0 Insert image bitmap to ms access database

Tags: database, image, ms-access, vb6, blob

Why doesn't my image get inserted? Here is my code.

```
Sub SaveToDBs(strImagePath As String, fname As String)
rs.Close
rs.Open "Sheet1", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable
Dim bytBLOB() As Byte
MsgBox strImagePath
Dim intNum As Integer
With rs   
    intNum = FreeFile
    Open strImagePath For Binary As #intNum
    ReDim bytBLOB(FileLen(strImagePath))
    'Read data and close file
    Get #intNum, , bytBLOB
    Close #1
    .Fields(fname).AppendChunk bytBLOB
    .Update
End With
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

I got "done" msgbox but image not inserted !!!!

Comment: Is your column `OLE Object` type? Do you use `Bound Object Frame` control to display the images?

Comment: @wqw Yes,That field is OLE Object type .

Answer (score 3):

I normally use ADODB.Stream for this sort of thing - I find it easier to understand than the chunking methods.

```
Sub SaveToDBs(strImagePath As String, fname As String)
rs.Close
rs.Open "Sheet1", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable
MsgBox strImagePath
Dim intNum As Integer
Dim myStream as ADODB.Stream
With rs      
    .AddNew
    Set myStream = new ADODB.Stream
    myStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    myStream.LoadFromFile(strImagePath)
    .Fields(fname) = myStream.Read
    .Update
    Set myStream = Nothing
End With
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

ADODB.Stream was added from ADO version 2.5:
[ADO Version History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676506%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[ADO Stream Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I think ADODB.Stream was added in MDAC 2.5, so if you are referencing an earlier version of MDAC it won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist bitmaps in structured storage for the MS Access binding to work as expected.

Take a look at Edanmo's [Load and save pictures to byte arrays.](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml) sample for a way to serialize in a compatible way. Then you could use *simple assignment* to update your recordset field if it's a client side one.