# Saving and loading jpg files in Microsoft Access database using Visual Basic

Tags: ms-access, vba, file-upload, jpeg

I'm a beginner in learning Visual Basic and Microsoft Access. May I know how to connect the two and how can I create a button that saves and loads JPG images in the database? Thank you very much.

Comment: See whether you can use one of the methods described in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641835/vb-6-0-insert-image-bitmap-to-ms-access-database  Personally I prefer not to store images in an Access database; instead I would save the image as a file and store only the path to that file in the database.

Comment: Are you using Visual Basic 6, VB.Net, or MS Access VBA?

Comment: I agree with @HansUp and always go with images on an external source with simple text references to their location, this will reduce the amount of space your db takes, which is good as access files do have limits, 2GB I think at the last check.

Comment: Even with large, enterprise databases, images are often only stored  as links.

Comment: To back up HansUp, here is an explanation why saving images in an Access DB is not a wise idea:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982688/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982688/)